# Redis Error On a Storm topology

Tags: redis, frontend, apache-storm, jedis

I'm using redis to extract the data from my **Storm topology**, I've been reading about it, and found some examples.

Now, I'm trying to make it run, and later I will implement a frontend to read from redis and make a **d3.js** implementation on a html file that would put the data on a chart. I have the D3 part implemented working for local files for now. At the moment, I'm not creating the mathematic functions for representing my data, I'm just creating tuples that read names from a text files, and appends the ":) :)" symbols. That part is working fine too, but I have the problem trying to use the *storm-redis*, on Storm 0.10.0.

As I understood for the moment(please correct me if I'm wrong) **redis** is a database such as mongoDB, non SQL and using fields for retrieving keys. I Have an implemerntation, but it's not working. I have an error compiling on a line, it's commented. Here is my code:

```
package Storm.practice.Storm.Prova;
import backtype.storm.Config;
import backtype.storm.LocalCluster;
import backtype.storm.StormSubmitter;
import backtype.storm.task.OutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import backtype.storm.testing.TestWordSpout;
import backtype.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import backtype.storm.topology.base.BaseRichBolt;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
import backtype.storm.tuple.ITuple;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Tuple;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Values;
import backtype.storm.utils.Utils;
import backtype.storm.spout.SpoutOutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.topology.base.BaseRichSpout;
import java.util.Map;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.apache.storm.redis.bolt.RedisStoreBolt;
import org.apache.storm.redis.common.config.JedisClusterConfig;
import org.apache.storm.redis.common.config.JedisPoolConfig;
import org.apache.storm.redis.common.mapper.RedisDataTypeDescription;
import org.apache.storm.redis.common.mapper.RedisStoreMapper;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisCommands;

/**
 * This is a basic example of a Storm topology.
 */
public class ProvaTopology {

  public static class ProvaBolt extends BaseRichBolt {
    OutputCollector _collector;

    public void prepare(Map conf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
      _collector = collector;
    }

    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
      _collector.emit(tuple, new Values(tuple.getString(0) + "  :-)"));
      _collector.ack(tuple);
    }

    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
      declarer.declare(new Fields("morts"));
    }


  }
  public class ProvaSpout extends BaseRichSpout {
      SpoutOutputCollector _collector;
      //Random _rand;
      private String fileName;
      //private SpoutOutputCollector _collector;
      private BufferedReader reader;
      private AtomicLong linesRead;

      public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
        _collector = collector;
        try {
            fileName= (String)"/home/prova.tsv";
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            // read and ignore the header if one exists
          } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
       // _rand = new Random();
      }

      public void nextTuple() {
        Utils.sleep(100);


      try {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line != null) {
              long id = linesRead.incrementAndGet();
              _collector.emit(new Values(line), id);
            } else {
              System.out.println("Finished reading file, " + linesRead.get() + " lines read");
              Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
        /*String[] sentences = new String[]{ "the cow jumped over the moon", "an apple a day keeps the doctor away",
            "four score and seven years ago", "snow white and the seven dwarfs", "i am at two with nature" };
        int _rand;*/
        //String sentence = sentences[_rand.nextInt(sentences.length)];
        //_collector.emit(new Values(sentence));


      public void ack(Object id) {
      }

      public void fail(Object id) {
      }

      public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("morts"));
      }

    }


  class MortsStoreMapper implements RedisStoreMapper {
        private RedisDataTypeDescription description;
        private final String hashKey = "Morts";

        public void MortsStoreStoreMapper() {
            description = new RedisDataTypeDescription(
                RedisDataTypeDescription.RedisDataType.HASH, hashKey);
        }


        public RedisDataTypeDescription getDataTypeDescription() {
            return description;
        }


        public String getKeyFromTuple(ITuple tuple) {
            return tuple.getStringByField("morts");
        }


        public String getValueFromTuple(ITuple tuple) {
            return tuple.getStringByField("somriures");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig.Builder()
            .setHost("127.0.0.1").setPort(666).build();
    RedisStoreMapper storeMapper = new MortsStoreMapper();**//ERROR HERE** Non enclosing instance of type ProvaTopology is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type ProvaTopology.
    RedisStoreBolt storeBolt = new RedisStoreBolt(poolConfig, storeMapper);

    builder.setSpout("morts", new TestWordSpout(), 10);//emisor
    builder.setBolt("happy", new ProvaBolt(), 3).shuffleGrouping("morts");// de on llig?
    builder.setBolt("meal", new ProvaBolt(), 2).shuffleGrouping("happy");// de on llig?

    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.setDebug(true);

    if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
      conf.setNumWorkers(3);

      StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[0], conf, builder.createTopology());
                                   //WithProgressBar
    }
    else {

      LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
      cluster.submitTopology("test", conf, builder.createTopology());
      Utils.sleep(10000);
      cluster.killTopology("test");
      cluster.shutdown();
    }
  }
}
```

Despite this error, once solved, I'm not sure my topology would save anything, and once saved, I'm a little lost on how to retrieve it with a frontend. Any help will be apreciated.

Thanks in advance

Here's a jedis implementation I've found on the web, at Storm-redis tutorial, and the one I'm using, just in case:

```
/**
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.apache.storm.redis.common.config;

import redis.clients.jedis.Protocol;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Configuration for JedisPool.
 */
public class JedisPoolConfig implements Serializable {
    public static final String DEFAULT_HOST = "127.0.0.1";

    private String host;
    private int port;
    private int timeout;
    private int database;
    private String password;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * <p/>
     * You can use JedisPoolConfig.Builder() for leaving some fields to apply default value.
     *
     * @param host hostname or IP
     * @param port port
     * @param timeout socket / connection timeout
     * @param database database index
     * @param password password, if any
     */
    public JedisPoolConfig(String host, int port, int timeout, String password, int database) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.timeout = timeout;
        this.database = database;
        this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     * Returns host.
     * @return hostname or IP
     */
    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    /**
     * Returns port.
     * @return port
     */
    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    /**
     * Returns timeout.
     * @return socket / connection timeout
     */
    public int getTimeout() {
        return timeout;
    }

    /**
     * Returns database index.
     * @return database index
     */
    public int getDatabase() {
        return database;
    }

    /**
     * Returns password.
     * @return password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /**
     * Builder for initializing JedisPoolConfig.
     */
    public static class Builder {
        private String host = DEFAULT_HOST;
        private int port = Protocol.DEFAULT_PORT;
        private int timeout = Protocol.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;
        private int database = Protocol.DEFAULT_DATABASE;
        private String password;

        /**
         * Sets host.
         * @param host host
         * @return Builder itself
         */
        public Builder setHost(String host) {
            this.host = host;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Sets port.
         * @param port port
         * @return Builder itself
         */
        public Builder setPort(int port) {
            this.port = port;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Sets timeout.
         * @param timeout timeout
         * @return Builder itself
         */
        public Builder setTimeout(int timeout) {
            this.timeout = timeout;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Sets database index.
         * @param database database index
         * @return Builder itself
         */
        public Builder setDatabase(int database) {
            this.database = database;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Sets password.
         * @param password password, if any
         * @return Builder itself
         */
        public Builder setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Builds JedisPoolConfig.
         * @return JedisPoolConfig
         */
        public JedisPoolConfig build() {
            return new JedisPoolConfig(host, port, timeout, password, database);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came with it! I just made it simple, I created a very simple redis bolt that publishes contents, I monitored the redis database, and it's working. My working bolt:

```
 public class RedisBolt implements IRichBolt {

        protected String channel = "Somriures";
        //    protected String configChannel;
        protected OutputCollector collector;
        //    protected Tuple currentTuple;
        //    protected Logger log;
        protected JedisPool pool;
        //    protected ConfigListenerThread configListenerThread;

        public RedisBolt(){}
        public RedisBolt(String channel) {

        //  log = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
        //  setupNonSerializableAttributes();
        }

        public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context,
                OutputCollector collector) {
        this.collector = collector;
        pool=new JedisPool("127.0.0.1");
          GenericObjectPoolConfig config = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();
        config.setMaxTotal(100);
        config.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        }



        public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
        String current = tuple.getString(0);
        if(current != null) {
            //      for(Object obj: result) {
            System.out.println("Publiquem " + current);
            publish(current);
            System.out.println("emitim " + current);
            collector.emit(tuple, new Values(current));
            //      }
            collector.ack(tuple);
        }
        }

        public void cleanup() {
        if(pool != null) {
            pool.destroy();
        }
        }

        public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields(channel));
        }

        public void publish(String msg) {
        Jedis jedis = pool.getResource();
        jedis.publish(channel, msg);

        pool.returnResource(jedis);
        }

        protected void setupNonSerializableAttributes() {

        }

        public Map getComponentConfiguration() {
        return null;
        }
    }
```